# Is this local variable shadowing/hiding another normal or a bug in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, variables, ambiguous

I've greatly simplified this question as the same problem arises in a simpler case:

```
#include <iostream>

int height;    
int main()
{
    std::cout << height; // Visual Studio debugger shows this value as -858993460    
    int height;
}
```

[image]

Seems a problem with the debugger displaying the wrong variable value. The variable value is correct, as printing the variable shows the correct global height value, 0.

Comment: Stripped it down further. The global `height` is initialised to zero by the standard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are correct, the global variable `height` is not *shadowed* until the declaration of the automatic variable `height` in the final statement of `main()`.

`std::cout << height;` will use the global variable `height`.

Yes, this is confusing the debugger. It's displaying the value of the *local* `height` variable, which in a debug build is initialized to `0xCCCCCCCC`, or the `-858993460` displayed in decimal mode.

The compiler does the correct thing and fetches the *global* variable `height` in the first line of the function, it's just the debugger that is confused.

Comment: Yes... I've just found out that it's the debugger which shows the false value of the local. If I std::cout it seems to print the right value. Ohhh, this is so frustrating. I'm sorry. I should delete this question, it's just a misleading Visual Studio debugger thing.

Comment: @Zebrafish: No, it's a good question and one that actually requires you to paste up the image. It might be an idea to simplify further and submit a bug report to MS.

Comment: I agree, I just tried it in VS2017 and it is definitely a bug in the debugger. If you could report the bug to MS that would be great, and keep the question here in case anyone else runs into it.

Comment: @Zebrafish: I've amended the answer to "catch up" with the question edits.

Comment: @MichaelGeary: I've wiki'd this so other folk can freely make edits to the answer, as we all explore how we can best demonstrate this to MS.